# How do I remove nginx?

Tags: 12.04, nginx

I have some problems with `nginx` configuration. I found the problem and I need to uninstall it. I used the commands

```
apt-get remove nginx
```

and

```
apt-get purge nginx
```

But the `nginx` is still runnning. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Find out what file is running:

```
pgrep nginx | xargs -I{} readlink -f /proc/{}/exe
```

Then you can expand on that to find out which package that file (or those files) belong to:

```
dpkg -S $(pgrep nginx | xargs -I{} readlink -f /proc/{}/exe | uniq)
```

In my case that highlights the `nginx-full` package but it might be you find a version of Nginx you manually installed (not from packages) that you now need to manually remove.

Comment: When I wrote the first command I got as response "/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nignx" .On the other hand when I have written the second command I got as response "dpkg-query:no path found matching patter /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx". What do I have to do now? Which package I have to remove?

Comment: Because it's in a `../local/..` directory that probably means you installed it manually (compiled from source, etc). The proper removal method really depends on how you installed it.